# Cannot mount Google Drive in Colab by clicking on icon

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I want to mount once for all my Google Drive in Colab for this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YbB_gA2_Rspmm1TDyEDueNXittmtWu1c?usp=sharing). Usually when I need to do so I just click on the icon on the upper left corner and after some additional clicks my Google Drive keeps mounted (even after "factory reset").

But here with this notebook every time I click on the icon, I get the following message :

> Run this cell to mount your Google Drive.

and a cell is added with the mounting code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

The problem with this mounting method is that I have to allow Colab to access Drive every time I "factory reset" the machine which happens often while changing codes on the notebook. So this is very cumbersome.

Do you know how I can allow the mount by clicking on the icon so that Colab remembers the mount forever (ie : until I revoke the access) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a workaround with regards to what I've experienced. This issue appears on Colab notebook that uses UI or interactive elements (widgets, sliders, dropdowns, play buttons, ...).

If you remove all these UI / interactive elements, you'll be able to mount your google Drive once and for all!